# Pass Negotiate authentication to IIS site

Tags: node.js, iis, kerberos

I have 3 IIS sites that call each other with HTTP. All the services are configured to work with Windows authorization.
[image]

The user authenticate to the Angular app with windows authentication. Service A is called from the Angular app in the browser. I can see that the Authorization header is passed like the following:

> "Authorization": "Negotiate YIIGpAYJKoZIhvcSAQICAQBuggaTMIIGj6AD...."

Now I need Service A to call Service B with the same credentials.
I tried to pass the same "Authorization" header but it didn't work. I get

> "www-authenticate": "Negotiate YHsGCSqGSIb3EgECAgMAfmwwaq..."

The www-authenticate response has different token.
What is the meaning of this response?

Is there a way to do that proper way to forward the user credentials between service A and service B?

Comment: Search for "kerberos delegation"